# Identifying a group by its generators and relations

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation

Let the group $G$ be defined by the generators $x,y$ and the relations $x^8=y^2=yxyx^5=e$, where $e$ is the neutral element, i.e.:

$$
G= \left<x,y \ | \ x^8=y^2=yxyx^5=e \right>
$$

I have to determine if $G$ is finite and provide a list of elements. Now by considering the last equality and using that $y^{-1}=y$:

$$
y^{-1}xy=x^{-5} \in \left< x \right>
$$

And thus $\left< x \right>$ is normal in $G$, furthermore we know that $\left< x \right> \leq C_8$, $\left< y \right> \leq C_2$, with $C_n$ the cyclic group of order $n$. This makes me think that $G \cong C_8 \times C_2$. How can I make this more rigorous/prove my suspicion?

Comment: You have $yx=x^3y$. The group cannot be abelian. It has order at most $16$. Look up "semidihedral group".

Comment: You might try a program like Magma which can compete things about finitely presented groups. This could help you identify the group so you know what you're actually trying to prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presentation that you have presented can be re-written as
$$
\langle x, y \mid x^8 = y^2 = e, y x y^{-1} = x^3\rangle,
$$
which is a canonical presentation of $G$ as an inner semidirect product $\langle x\rangle \rtimes \langle y\rangle$.

To be more explicit, note that since $\langle x \rangle$ is normal, any element of $G$ can be written as $x^a y^b$ for some $a \in C_8, b \in C_2$ (you should show this).
We can then compute the product of two elements $x^a y^b \cdot x^{a'} y^{b'}$.
If $b = 0$, we have $x^a y^b \cdot x^{a'} y^{b'} = x^{a+a'}y^{b'} = x^{a+a'}y^{b + b'}$, whereas if $b=1$, we can use the conjugation relation to see that $yx = x^3y$, and so
$$
x^a y \cdot x^{a'}y^{b'}
= x^a (x^3 y) x^{a'-1} y^{b'}
= \dotsb
= x^a (x^{3a'} y) y^{b'}
= x^{a + 3a'} y^{b + b'}.
$$

Putting these together, we can write $x^a y^b \cdot x^{a'}y^{b'} = x^{a + (2b+1)a'} y^{b+ b'}$.

Let $\varphi\colon C_2 \rightarrow\mathrm{Aut}(C_8)$ be defined by $\varphi(b) \colon a \mapsto (2b + 1)a$ (this is an automorphism since $3$ and $8$ are coprime), which is a homomorphism and satisfies $x^a y^b \cdot x^{a'}y^{b'} = x^{a + \varphi(b)(a')} y^{b+ b'}$.
But this exactly means that the map
\begin{align*}
\lambda \colon\; G &\rightarrow C_8 \rtimes_\varphi C_2 \\
x^a y^b &\mapsto (a, b)
\end{align*}
is a homomorphism and so, since each $x^a y^b$ is distinct for $a \in C_8, b \in C_2$, an isomorphism.
That is, $G \cong C_8 \rtimes_\varphi C_2$.

Comment: You have the semidirect product symbol pointing the wrong way. It should be $\langle x\rangle\rtimes \langle y\rangle$, since the subgroup generated by $x$ is normal, so the "normal in" part of the symbol should have the verte. pointing to the normal subgroup.

Comment: Whoops, somehow I can never get that right!

Comment: The easy way to remember is to think of half of the symbol as the "normal in" symbol; that half has the normal subgroup in the usual position.

Answer (score 1):

Arturo's comment is correct. This group is [The Semidihedral Group order 16](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Semidihedral_group:SD16)

The elements $\{e, x, ..., x^7, y, yx, ..., yx^7\}$ are unique, and complete since any other $x^ny^m$ can be expressed as one of these using $x^n=x^{n\ mod\ 8}$, $y^m=y^{m\ mod\ 2}$ and $xy=yx^3$. Likewise for any $y^mx^n$. The conjugation trick in Damian's answer gives you every product $(x^{n_1}y^{n_2})(x^{n_3}y^{n_4})\cdots$ in the form $y^mx^n$ where $m=(\sum_{i\ even}n_i)$ mod $2$ and $n=(\sum_{i\ odd}3n_i)$ mod $8$, which is on the list.